# Selecting a cell in Excel based on variable containing the row number

Tags: excel, vba

How would I select a cell based on a variable `beginPosition` containing the row number. For example if my beginPosition variable is 10, how would I select cell A10?

I tried using the Range function, but that is not working very well (erroring out).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Range("A" & beginPosition).Select
```

Comment: I assumed beginPosition was the excel row number, is that correct?

Comment: Personally I prefer `Cells(1, beginPosition).Select`. This way it's easier to make variables for columns too.

Comment: Actually, I think it should be Cells(beginPosition,1).Select

Comment: Actually, I think it should be Cells(beginPosition,1).Select. This is in response to the post saying to use Cells(1,beginPosition).Select. I repeated this post because I thought it would show up next to the comment I meant it for, but it didn't.

Answer (score 12):

Use INDIRECT function

e.g if cell A1 has 4 the function =INDIRECT("C"&A1) will return the contents of cell C4.

http://www.freelists.org/post/mso/ExcelVariable-cell-reference,5